# A question about Green's Theorem path intervall

Tags: vector-analysis

If we have$\displaystyle \int _{C} \ \frac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2+y^2}$, where $C$ is postive oriented with the ellipse $x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$ from $(1,0) \ to \ (0,-2)$

Then $\displaystyle \iint_C {\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}}\ dxdy $  becomes zero. So I choose a path (1/4 of a unit circle) and the I get

$\displaystyle \int _{C} \ \frac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2+y^2}= \int \ (sin^2(\theta) + cos^2 (\theta)) \ d\theta= d\theta $ after paramertizing the unit circle as usual.

BUT, the main question is, is the interval for $\displaystyle \theta$ $ \ $ $\displaystyle \frac{3\pi}{2} \to 2\pi$ or  $\displaystyle \frac{3\pi}{2} \to 0$??? According to the correct answer, which is $\frac{3 \pi}{2}$, it should be the second interval! But why?

Thanks.

Comment: Form $(1,0)$ to $(0,-2)$ means that $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $3\pi\over 2$

Comment: why not the second case??

Comment: @Thomas, Oh I got it, my figure which I drew (false), made me confused. Thanks!!